# How addPlot to bsdoc document in ReporteRs package?

Tags: r, reporters

I am trying to add a plot to a bsdoc in ReporteRs package. When I run the example on the [tutorial site](https://davidgohel.github.io/ReporteRs/bsdoc.html) it only gives back the table. The plot is nowhere to be seen. Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong? I am using a virtual machine and tried different browsers (IE, chrome, Firefox) with no success.

```
library( ReporteRs )

# Creation of mydoc
mydoc = bsdoc( title = 'my document' )

# add into mydoc first 10 lines of iris
mydoc = addFlexTable( mydoc, vanilla.table(iris[1:10,] ) )

mydoc = addParagraph( mydoc, value = "Hello World!" )

# add a plot into mydoc 
mydoc = addPlot( mydoc, function() barplot( 1:8, col = 1:8 ) )

# write the doc 
writeDoc( mydoc, file = "examples/htmloutput/bsdoc_simple_example.html" )
```

*EDIT* The tutorial says "Note that other files will be copied in the directory containing the html file (i.e. the bootstrap css, js directories)." 
In my case that does not happen. So mayby that's the cause of my problem. Still I have no clue how to solve that.

*EDIT2* The html output contains a link that says 'Skip to main content'. Isn't that a bit strange as well?

Comment: Does examples/htmloutput already exist ? If I run your code above, it works for me, it creates the directory and copy js, css files in it with the html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this problem is the folder should not be already created .It should be created by the module.

> I ran the above method using both by creating the folder and not creating it

The js,css and other files are only created when the `folder is not available`

> The function needs to create a folder not necessarily `examples/htmloutput/`
>
> i.e.

```
writeDoc( mydoc, file = "outputs/bsdoc_simple_example.html" )
```

Will create a folder if it not available and create all needed files in the folder **BUT** if the is available then it will only create the HTML file